# Create table with fixed columns and variable rows using CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS/HTML .
Can anyone tell me how to go about creating table with variable number of rows .What do we have in CSS
I want to create a table with similar structure
i am confused how to define properties in CSS and access them in html.A small example will be helpful
[Link to table](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_fancy)

Comment: To be honest, I can't understand what's your exact issue based on your question... "confused how to define properties in CSS and access them in html" this actually should be simple... define classes or and pass them to your `html` elements as attribute `class`. Please add what you did try till now (your code) as @Paulie_D has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way add bootstrap in your project and copy html code if you not needed custom css. Follow the below link:

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/
```

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Comment: @Paulie_D My answer is not relative question but is not wrong so why to negative marking.